# How to print 10 9 8 7 6 in first line and 10 9 8 7 in second line in java using while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

How to print 10 9 8 7 6 in first line and 10 9 8 7 in second line in java using while loop? how to change from first line to second?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  int i=10;
  while (i>=1)
  {
   System.out.print(i+" ");
   i=i-1;
  }
  int j=10;
  while (j>=2)
  {
   System.out.print("\n"+j);
   j=j-1;
  }
 }

Comment: you can check below code.

Answer (score 1):

Need to use **two while loops**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i =10;
        int count =5;
        while(i>=count){
            int j=i;
            while(j>count){
                System.out.print(j+" ");
                j--;
            }
            System.out.println();
            count++;
        }
    }
```

**output**

```
10 9 8 7 6 
10 9 8 7 
10 9 8 
10 9 
10
```

Comment: OP *was* using two while loops (in comment to question). The important part is they have to be **nested**. Which you did. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
  int x = 10;
  int i = 0;
  int n = 6;
  while(i++ < n) {
    while( i++ < n ) {
      System.out.print(x-- + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
    x = 10;
    i = 0;
    n = n-1;
   }
  }
 }
```

OutPut :

10 9 8 7 6

10 9 8 7

10 9 8

10 9

10

Answer (score 0):

Using while loop :

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x = 10;
        int i = 4;
        while(i<=4 && i >= 0){
            int j=0;
            while(j<=i){
                int h = (x - j);
                System.out.print(h + " ");
                j++;
            }
            i--;
            System.out.print("\n");
            if(i<=2)break;
        }
   }
}
```

Using For loop :

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x = 10;

        for(int i=4;i>=0;i--){
            for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){
                int h = (x - j);
                System.out.print(h + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
            if(i<=3)break;
        }
   }
}
```

output:

```
10 9 8 7 6 
10 9 8 7
```

if you want to output like this below :

```
10 9 8 7 6 
10 9 8 7 
10 9 8 
10 9 
10
```

You need to comment out `if(i<=2)break;` or for loop `if(i<=3)break;`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to say `i>2` and drop the `break`?

Comment: Alright I'll update it :D